# Is there a way to know if there are any observers for CDI events?

Tags: java, events, cdi

I have a `Button` in my UI that should not always be added. The only thing it does is firing a CDI event when clicked.

Now I'd like to prevent adding the `Button` to the UI if there is no bean observing that event. Is there a way to see if there are any observers on the injected `Event` object or preventing injection of it so I can check if it is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
@Inject
private BeanManager beanManager;

...

Set<ObserverMethod<? super Document>> observers = 
    beanManager.resolveObserverMethods(
        new Document(), new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {});
observers.isEmpty();
```

(Although it might not be the best architecture. Later you might have an observer which simply has an empty implementation or just ignores the event based on a runtime condition.)

Comment: Thanks. It works. Unfortunately observers also holds `ObserverMethod` objects for Methods annotated like this @Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS) even if no bean exists